# Natural domain for the real function $f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{t^2-9}dt$

Tags: real-analysis

Q. What is the natural domain for the real function $f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{t^2-9}dt$.

For the values $x \in [0,3)$, it is clear to me that integral is well defined. But, Can we take the naural domain as $\mathbb R -\{-3,3\}$? Is it sensible while getting $\int_0^x \frac{1}{t^2-9}dt=\ln|\frac{x-3}{x+3}|$ to take all the values in $\mathbb R -\{-3,3\}$ for $x$? What is the consequence of trying $f(4)=\int_0^4 \frac{1}{t^2-9}dt=\int_0^3 \frac{1}{t^2-9}dt+\int_3^4 \frac{1}{t^2-9}dt$.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The domain is $\mathbb R -\{-3,3\}$. The last integrals you wrote are not convergent and you must define the two on the right-hand side as improper integral.